# Mass data loading on table where foreign key reference primary key in same table

Tags: sql-server

I'm teaching myself SQL Server but have a background with "relational" databases for many years and understand keys and their linking relationships.

I have list of pre-defined INSERTS that I found somewhere and am trying and create a "employees" table.  Within the table is a primary key on employee_id and with a foreign key on manager_id, references back to employee_id creating a hierarchy.

```
  (
    employee_id NUMERIC(3)
    PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL,
    last_name  VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL,
    email      VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL,
    phone      VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
    hire_date  DATE NOT NULL          ,
    manager_id NUMERIC(3)        , -- fk
    job_title  VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_employees_manager 
        FOREIGN KEY( manager_id )
        REFERENCES employees( employee_id )
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
  )

Here is snipet of INSERTS:
Insert into EMPLOYEES 
(EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (107,'Summer','Payne','summer.payne@example.com','515.123.8181','07-JUN-16',106,'Public Accountant');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (106,'Rose','Stephens','rose.stephens@example.com','515.123.8080','07-JUN-16',2,'Accounting Manager');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (101,'Annabelle','Dunn','annabelle.dunn@example.com','515.123.4444','17-SEP-16',2,'Administration Assistant');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (1,'Tommy','Bailey','tommy.bailey@example.com','515.123.4567','17-JUN-16',null,'President');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (3,'Blake','Cooper','blake.cooper@example.com','515.123.4569','13-JAN-16',1,'Administration Vice President');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (2,'Jude','Rivera','jude.rivera@example.com','515.123.4568','21-SEP-16',1,'Administration Vice President');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (11,'Tyler','Ramirez','tyler.ramirez@example.com','515.124.4269','28-SEP-16',9,'Accountant');
```

Upon trying to INSERT the data, I get an error stating:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint "fk_employees_manager". The conflict occurred in database "MyDB", table "dbo.employees", column 'employee_id'.
```

I understand I'm trying to add employee 107 with a manager id of 106 but as being the first INSERT, employee (or a manager) id 106 doesn't exist (yet).

So my quick solution was to create the employees table WITHOUT to foreign key, execute all of the inserts, then finally ALTER the employees table to add the foreign key on manager_id referencing to employee_id.
This worked with no errors.

But I'd like to know if there is a better way to do this.  I'm semi aware of the ON CASCADE ON UPDATE, etc features on adding a foreign key, but not sure how/syntax to make this work when creating the table (before data loading).

Comment: What you described as the solution sounds like the best way to handle this. You simply can't insert a row into a table if the foreign key value doesn't exist.

Comment: Since `manager_id` allows `NULL`s you could also first insert all rows with `manager_id` being `NULL` and then update the table to set the managers when all employees are there.

Comment: "Best way" is very subjective. If you insert values into the table without the FK constraint, you run the risk of using values that are not (or will not) actually be found as PK values when the constraint is added. You might consider inserting "top down" - that is, insert all employees that have no manager, insert those employees that report to this top level, etc.

Comment: @stickybit - Ok I understand this and had thought of this. To insert all of the rows, but with the each employee having their manager_id as NULL.  Then have another update on each employee, updating their manager_ids.  I was just wondering if there was a all encompassing way to do this in the initial creation of the table.

Comment: @SMor - wrong terms... "More effiecient way" is probably better way of asking.  But yes, rearranging the INSERTs, I had thought, work as well but very time consuming.  Again, just something I found on internet.

Comment: @SeanLange - thank you for your input!